# "Contemporary" vs. "contemporaneous"

Tags: differences, adjectives, time

What is the difference between these two words?

> [contemporary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contemporary): From the same time period, coexistent in time.
>
> [contemporaneous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contemporaneous): Existing or created in the same period of time.

I know that *contemporary* has a second meaning (*modern*), but I'm asking about the above sense. Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 5):

> **Contemporary** and **contemporaneous** both mean *originating, existing, or happening during the same period*. But although
>   these adjectives are close in
>   definition, they’re used slightly
>   differently.
>
> *Contemporary* usually applies to people or small groups of people. For
>   example, the Beatles and the Beach
>   Boys were contemporary with each other
>   because they were active at roughly
>   the same time. *Contemporaneous*
>   usually applies to events, movements,
>   or trends. For example, the rise of
>   rock music was contemporaneous with
>   the economic boom and counterculture
>   movements of the 1950s and ‘60s.
>
> The definition of *contemporaneous* is
>   narrow, confined to this one sense.
>   *Contemporary* is broader; sometimes it means current or modern, and it’s
>   also a noun denoting a person who
>   exists at the same time as another.
>
> ### Examples
>
> These writers demonstrate correct
>   usage of *contemporary*:
>
> - The gallery began collecting contemporary works, mainly through
>     Britain, which understandably remained
>     our window on to the world of art . .
>     . [Australian]
> - Vermeer and Metsu were contemporaries, but Metsu was the star
>     in the Golden Age of Dutch painting
>     during the 17th century . . . [NPR]
> - The three-way race nicely illustrates the tensions within the
>     contemporary GOP. [Telegraph]
>
> And these writers use the less common
>   *contemporaneous* correctly:
>
> - The change in the holiday was contemporaneous with a larger change
>     in attitude among many American toward
>     their government . . . [Taunton Daily
>     Gazette]
> - This point is underlined at the exhibition by the inclusion of
>     contemporaneous works of rivals such
>     as Kitagawa Utamaro. [Japan Times]
> - They judge the past not by contemporaneous standards but by their
>     own politically correct notions . . .
>     [Washington Examiner]

[*Resource: [grammarist.com](http://www.grammarist.com/usage/contemporary-contemporaneous/)*]

Comment: The two first examples seem to use _contemporary_ in other senses (as _modern_ and as a noun), and I don't understand the context of the third example enough to decide the meaning of the word there. Do you have another example?

Comment: Copy & paste dumps from other sources are frowned upon and may violate copyright, even when a citation is provided.

Answer (score 3):

When not used to mean "modern," *contemporary* is usually used as a noun, meaning one that was  (or is) alive or active at the same time as another: "Shakespeare's contemporary, Christopher Marlowe, is not as well remembered today." *Contemporaneous* is never used in this way; it is always an adjective.

As you note, *contemporary* as an adjective can mean both "modern" and "from the same time period [as another]," whereas *contemporaneous* only takes the second definition. *Contemporaneous works* about the 16th century were written and/or published in or near the 16th century, whereas *contemporary works* about the 16th century were probably published recently (although not necessarily; there is potential for ambiguity here).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say this, and was glad to find it [corroborated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contemporary): "Contemporary is used more often of persons, contemporaneous of events and facts". Otherwise, and aside from the fact that "contemporary" can also be a noun, they are synonymous in the sense that you are asking about.

Comment: What about other objects that aren't people? for instance would it be OK to say that the Tandy TRS-80 was a contemporary of the Commodore PET?